# FullCalendar - Retrieve fileId of Attachments in Google Calendar

Tags: fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I'm hoping to find some help retrieving the Google Calendar attachment fileId through FullCalendar v2.9.0.

The Google calendar is dedicated to this project and is public as is the Drive folder containing image files which are the attachments - one image per event.  I am new to the details of Javascript, but I've searched and researched quite a bit. I have not been able to find an example or tutorial that is close enough to what I'm trying to do that I can understand.

My project involves a month view FullCalendar where a user clicks an event, the event background highlights and a sidebar div populates with title, dateTime, description, location, and attachment image file. The user would browse through multiple events with the sidebar updating accordingly.

Here's what I've done so far:

The Google calendar elements are populating and updating correctly except for the image attachment.

I can hard code the HTML in gcal.html with a URL appended with the attachment fileId and get the image in the sidebar. The image, of course, is static though.

Using Google API Explorer calendar.events.get and entering calendarId, eventId, and simple API key, all of which are retrievable from FullCalendar, API Explorer returns the attachment fileId,
(Note that the fileUrl below works in a browser pulling up a viewer, but does not work in my HTML. This one does though: "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B5Nk_tOCzCISaWdqYy1DYnF6SzA")

From API Explorer

```
Execute without OAuth
calendar.events.get executed 16 minutes ago time to execute: 282 ms
Request


GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/c6kag4dlhqs7m160s3t3lfggak%40group.calendar.google.com/events/u9a5fuoqkfmkm2c20vpn75krf4?fields=attachments(fileId%2CfileUrl)&key={YOUR_API_KEY}


Response


200

- Show headers -

{
 "attachments": [
  {
   "fileUrl": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5Nk_tOCzCISaWdqYy1DYnF6SzA/view?usp=drive_web",
   "fileId": "0B5Nk_tOCzCISaWdqYy1DYnF6SzA"
  }
 ]
}
```

I've tried what seems like endless combinations of statements, basically guessing, at the right syntax in a gcal.html eventClick function. I've also been trying to add code to events.push in gcal.js. This is the only place where I can find other event elements referenced.

My current setup with "alert(event.fileid);" under eventClick ingcal.html and "attachments: entry.fileid" under events.push in gcal.js returns an alert "undefined". In gcal.js a few lines down I notice "`successArgs = [ events ].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));` // forward other jq args". I'm wondering if FullCalendar returns all fields for an event?

gcal.html (head)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8' />
  <link href='../fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <link href='../fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
  <script src='../lib/moment.min.js'></script>
  <script src='../lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='../fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
  <script src='../gcal.js'></script>
  <script>

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      eventLimit: 4,

      googleCalendarApiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',

      events: {
        googleCalendarId: 'c6kag4dlhqs7m160s3t3lfggak@group.calendar.google.com'
      },

      //$('#calendar'.fullCalendar( 'clientEvents' [, filter ] )  
      // Need to highlight next upcoming event on page load
      //        var filter = (events, event.start > getdate(new))   

      eventClick: function(event, events ) {

        alert(event.fileid);

        //eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
        // Need to reset highlight on prevoiusly clicked event
        //      element.css('background-color', '#5777c8');
        //}
        //$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'updateEvents' );

        $( "#sidebar2" ).html(event.title);
        $( "#sidebar3" ).html(event.start.format('dddd MMM. Do'));
        $( "#sidebar4" ).html(event.start.format('h:mm a'));
        $( "#sidebar5" ).html(event.description);
        $( "#sidebar6" ).html(
          '<a style= color:#a2cadc; href=http://' + 
          event.location + ' target="_blank">' + 
          "More Band Info" + '</a>'
        );
        $(this).css('background-color', '#5777c8');
        return false;
        console.log

      },        

      loading: function(bool) {
        $('#loading').toggle(bool);
      }     

    });

  });

</script>
```

gcal.js (line 122 to end)

```
return $.extend({}, sourceOptions, {
  googleCalendarId: null, // prevents source-normalizing from happening again
  url: url,
  data: data,
  startParam: false, // `false` omits this parameter. we already included it above
  endParam: false, // same
  timezoneParam: false, // same
  success: function(data) {
    var events = [];
    var successArgs;
    var successRes;

    if (data.error) {
      reportError('Google Calendar API: ' + data.error.message, data.error.errors);
    }
    else if (data.items) {
      $.each(data.items, function(i, entry) {
        var url = entry.htmlLink || null;

        // make the URLs for each event show times in the correct timezone
        if (timezoneArg && url !== null) {
          url = injectQsComponent(url, 'ctz=' + timezoneArg);
        }

        events.push({
          id: entry.id,
          title: entry.summary,
          start: entry.start.dateTime || entry.start.date, 
     // try timed. will fall back to all-day
          end: entry.end.dateTime || entry.end.date, // same
          url: url,
          location: entry.location,
          description: entry.description,
          attachments: entry.fileid  // tryiing to find the attachment reference
        });
      });

      // call the success handler(s) and allow it to return a new events array
      successArgs = [ events ].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)); 
      // forward other jq args
      successRes = applyAll(success, this, successArgs);
      if ($.isArray(successRes)) {
        return successRes;
      }
    }

    return events;
  }
});
}

// Injects a string like "arg=value" into the querystring of a URL
function injectQsComponent(url, component) {
  // inject it after the querystring but before the fragment
  return url.replace(/(\?.*?)?(#|$)/, function(whole, qs, hash) {
    return (qs ? qs + '&' : '?') + component + hash;
  });
}
});
```

Any help to get this working would be greatly appreciated.